# Parsing multipart/mixed responses

Tags: httpresponse, httpwebresponse, adobe-pdfservices

I want to parse a `multipart/mixed` web response I'm getting in to proper content,

```
    --Boundary_33046_835445861_1627668603035
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="contentAnalyzerResponse"

{"cpf:inputs":{"documentIn":{"cpf:location":"InputFile0","dc:format":"application/pdf"},"params":{"cpf:inline":{"elementsToExtract":["text","tables"],"renditionsToExtract":["tables","figures"]}}},"cpf:engine":{"repo:assetId":"urn:aaid:cpf:58af6e2c-1f0c-400d-9188-078000185695"},"cpf:status":{"completed":true,"type":"","status":200},"cpf:outputs":{"elementsRenditions":[{"cpf:location":"fileoutpart0","dc:format":"image/png"},{"cpf:location":"fileoutpart1","dc:format":"image/png"},{"cpf:location":"fileoutpart2","dc:format":"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"},{"cpf:location":"fileoutpart3","dc:format":"image/png"},{"cpf:location":"fileoutpart4","dc:format":"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"},{"cpf:location":"fileoutpart5","dc:format":"image/png"},{"cpf:location":"fileoutpart6","dc:format":"image/png"},{"cpf:location":"fileoutpart7","dc:format":"image/png"},{"cpf:location":"fileoutpart8","dc:format":"image/png"},{"cpf:location":"fileoutpart9","dc:format":"image/png"},{"cpf:location":"fileoutpart10","dc:format":"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"},{"cpf:location":"fileoutpart11","dc:format":"image/png"},{"cpf:location":"fileoutpart12","dc:format":"application/vnd.
```

```
--Boundary_33046_835445861_1627668603035
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileoutpart92"

�PNG

�޾�L���޺S�|��wp���F��k�^����{��{�d\'�����|v������Q<H=||�϶�7����yHBz��q���o݉մ�\:���/�[Ó���:��   ����Tկ�����K�/|g��HY��F�����/��ݳ/�7�6�w$������F��sZ�0T�I��p���0�힍��:�J�����_��>���k��9~���C�P��Pl3���K\�:�ʵ����?z��G�w�V��_yg/�������~Z_3��W����x�[���N�9U}�E�~|�g��:�u��m�B��ZQ����z�O��=W�=gܪ�|x�2����o|pU��/���~�����ޒ������}����}�W���v���k��pM�yI��I<�t�w��
���}~�����M<����7~�c�l���gF��?���o�!` ��0�G�ioG.ީ������^��S�96Ź��a8K�{�N�paa8�<�1���p�]؝�>�x�#Y�z���y�����w>s�K���c�5��pQ�b����i���3�8���������&�h>?wo���{���WjɅO݉�T�w���8��:�ut�̩�Eu����&^���>sʸmk<������1
��oB"�0�    �������ƾ��ܴ�a8c�u�~��<%0
```

The response I'm getting is similar to the responses above and I want to get the individual content from the response.

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: I'm using .net, sorry forgot to mention that.

Comment: Have you considered using the SDK instead?